# Installing Ghostscript in Linux

Tags: linux, ghostscript

I'm trying to install Ghostscript on my web server but the instructions on the website don't seem to work for me.

I'm logged into my ssh terminal.

I type in:

```
wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/binaries/ghostscript-9.18-linux-x86_64.tgz
```

Then:

```
tar -zxvf ghostscript-9.18-linux-x86_64.tgz

cd ghostscript-9.18-linux-x86_64
```

Then the documentation says I just need to run `./configure`, however that doesn't seem to do anything. There's a single executable file inside however when I run it it just takes me to the Ghostscript prompt rather than installing Ghostscript.

I'm a newbie at this so keep it simple.

Answer (score 5):

Use your packet manager, for example, on RedHat and derivatives:

`yum install ghostscript`

Or on Debian:

`apt-get install ghostscript`

Comment: When I type that into the shell I receive the following error:

CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

Comment: probably because you are trying as non-root user. 
try add "sudo" before the command. 
Or login as root to do so.

Comment: I don't have root on my host. When I type in what you said I get the following result:
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: I also needed to run this: `sudo apt install graphicsmagick`

Answer (score 1):

The file you downloaded contains a compiled version of Ghostscript, not source code, so the instructions for how to build from source code do not apply. This is also explained to some degree by the supplied `README.txt` file.

Like Fredi said, you should normally use your distribution's packaged version. This is *especially* true if you aren't particularly familiar with Linux. The proper way to do that should be to run `sudo yum install ghostscript` or something very similar.

If you really do want to build from source, go to [the Ghostscript download page](http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and download the package labelled "Ghostscript 9.18 Source" instead of the package labelled "Ghostscript 9.18 for Linux x86 (64 bit)". You should then be able to follow the instructions for building from source code.

Comment: I tried downloading the redhat rpm however it gives me an error when I run it:

error: ghostscript-8.70-23.4.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 2ca06d46: BAD
error: ghostscript-8.70-23.4.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said your file is a binary.

The easiest way to install it in your system is to put it,  (or replace an existing version of Ghostscript), in **/usr/local/bin** under the name **gs**

```
cd ghostscript-9.18-linux-x86_64
sudo cp gs-918-linux_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/gs
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gs
```

A few controls:

```
which gs # Should answer **/usr/local/bin/gs**
gs --version # Should answer **9.18**
```

Then you are good to go:-)

/Paul